# How to set the color/background of an Ellipse with a color chosen via a ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

This is in code behind window

```
public WpfTestWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ComboboxCOLOR.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
}
```

This is the `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboboxCOLOR" Height="25"  Width="180">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And - whatever color is chosen in `ComboBox`: It should fill up this `Ellipse` with that color;
Here below what I got at the moment, it doesnt work...

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding ComboboxCOLOR}" Name="Ellipse"
         Margin="5" Height="40" Width="40" 
         Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5">
</Ellipse>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the `ComboBox` using the [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=net-5.0) in the binding.

> Gets or sets the name of the element to use as the binding source object.

If you do not specify the element name, the binding markup extension will interpret `ComboboxCOLOR` as a property on the current data context of the `Ellipse` element. Then use the `SelectedItem` property and the `Name` property of the item as in your example to bind the `Fill`

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=ComboboxCOLOR}" Name="Ellipse"
         Margin="5" Height="40" Width="40" 
         Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5">
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Makes sense, thatguy, But it still doesnt work.  The "fill" in the Ellipse stayed unchanged when i tried your solution.

Comment: @TdW Please post the relevant XAML code, where both controls are used, otherwise it is hard to determine where the issue is and why the binding is not working.

Comment: @TdW The XAML that shows how the controls are related. E.g. are the controls in two different windows? If yes, then of course the element name binding will not work. If they are in the same XAML file, is the combo box in the scope of the ellipse? Are the controls in templates, user controls or anywhere else? The isolated code of both controls as in your question does not help in this regard.

Comment: AYAYAYA, sry !!! I tried your solution again, and now it works ...
No idea why it didnt the first attempt, but ... 

THX ALOT for the correct answer !